# My doubt is regarding the lorentz force

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, forces, vectors, conventions

Consider a magnetic field in the positive z direction, and a charge +q moves with a velocity along the positive x direction. How do we know in which direction lorentz force on charge will be acting?

Comment: I don't understand your confusion. The force is given by the right-hand rule, and will be in the negative-y direction.

Comment: @RdBasha The topic was recently taught to us in school, so I had some doubt in it. Thank you for your time

Answer (score 2):

You can use the equation for the magnetic force to find it's direction:

$$\vec {F}_B = q(\vec v \times \vec B)$$
Clearly, the vector $\vec{F}_B$ is along $\vec v \times \vec B$. According to your question, $\vec v$ is along $\hat {i}$ and $\vec B$ along $\hat{k}$, so $\vec{F}_B$ is along $\hat {i} \times \hat {k} = -\hat{j}$, which is along the negative y - axis. You can alternatively use the [right hand rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-hand_rule) as well.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much . This was very helpful